# How can I control the keyboard smoothly like a facebook messenger?

Tags: ios, keyboard, controls, ios10

in facebook messenger’s chatroom screen, We can scroll up the tableview to slide up keyboard and scroll down the tableview to slide down keyboard. in this situation, the keyboard is following my finger’s scroll action.

I can call the keyboard to show or hide, but i just can listen willShow, didshow, etc.. I can not access keyboard action or animation.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`UIScrollView` has a property called `keyboardDismissMode` that allows you to set different behaviors.

```
scrollview.keyboardDismissMode = UIScrollViewKeyboardDismissModeInteractive;
```

Simply you can use-

```
scrollView.keyboardDismissMode = UIScrollViewKeyboardDismissModeOnDrag;
```